# Converting string of ascii characters into their ascii numbers and assigning them to a variable

Tags: python, string, ascii

I'm trying to convert whatever the user enters into ascii numbers but using this method doesn't seem to work and I don't know what the problem is?

```
message = input ("Enter message to be encrypted: ")
message_numbers = ""

for i in message:
    message_numbers1 = [ord(c) for c in message]
    message_numbers = message_numbers + message_numbers1

print (message_numbers)
```

Comment: What the... what?! You're iterating over `message`, then again in a list comprehension (completely ignoring the character `i`), then trying to add the resulting list to a string? What were you expecting to happen? Try replacing everything below the `input` line with simply `print([ord(c) for c in message])` (or even `print(*map(ord, message))`).

Comment: Is the expected output the ascii numbers of the characters entered as input in a string?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to iterate over message and then use list comprehension to iterate again over message, stick to one.

If the expected output is the ascii numbers of the characters entered as input in a string , then you are missing converting the list of ascii numbers to string , for that you can use the `string.join` function -

```
message = input ("Enter message to be encrypted: ")

message_numbers1 = [ord(c) for c in message]
message_numbers = message_numbers + ''.join(map(str, message_numbers1))

print (message_numbers)
```

Please note, input to `join` function is a iterable list_like of strings , hence I converted the message_numbers1 to string using `map` .

If `message_numbers1` would not be used anywhere else, you can also directly create strings in it, like below -

```
message_numbers1 = [str(ord(c)) for c in message]
```

In this case, you can directly use -

```
message_numbers = message_numbers + ''.join(message_numbers1)
```

Comment: Why bother initialising `message_numbers = ""` then having `message_numbers = message_numbers + ...` (not least because `message_numbers += ...` would simplify things)?

Comment: Already added the second part about `str(ord(c))` to the second part of the answer